# Object Comparison in JAVA...Part 2

Tags: java, object, comparison, equals, hashcode

This post is continuation of my previous post found here

[Object comparison for equality : JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237686/object-comparison-for-equality-java)

Based on the suggestions I received, I created the following class and did a equals(), hashcode() override ....everything using Eclipse IDE. However I still get a false when I compare two different objects which reference the same class using the contains() method of an arraylist in which these objects are stored. I dont know what is wrong in my implementation. Would like help troubleshooting.

```
public class ClassA {

private String firstId;
private String secondId;
/**
 * @return the firstId
 */
public String getFirstId() {
    return firstId;
}
/**
 * @param firstId the firstId to set
 */
public void setFirstId(String firstId) {
    this.firstId = firstId;
}
/**
 * @return the secondId
 */
public String getSecondId() {
    return secondId;
}
/**
 * @param secondId the secondId to set
 */
public void setSecondId(String secondId) {
    this.secondId = secondId;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
public int hashCode() {
    final int PRIME = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = PRIME * result + ((firstId == null) ? 0 : firstId.hashCode());
    result = PRIME * result + ((secondId == null) ? 0 : secondId.hashCode());
    return result;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    final ClassA other = (ClassA) obj;
    if (firstId == null) {
        if (other.firstId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstId.equals(other.firstId))
        return false;
    if (secondId == null) {
        if (other.secondId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!secondId.equals(other.secondId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}

ClassA clsA1 = new ClassA();
ClassA clsA2 = new ClassA();

clsA1.setFirstId("value1");
clsA1.setSecondId("value2");

clsA2.setFirstId("value1");
clsA2.setSecondId("value2");

ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList();

a1.add(clsA1);
a2.add(clsA2);

if(a1.contains(clsA2)
{
    System.out.println("Success");
}
else
{ 
    System.out.println("Failure");
}
```

I get the result as "Failure"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code, I get Success, in Netbeans. There is a Typo a missing ")" in 
if(a1.contains(clsA2)

"Of course it fails. Your id Strings are null in your test code, and the equals method is written to return false if this occurs. Perhaps you should allow equality if both firstId and secondId are null, or if either is null and both of the other match." 
Isn't really right.

If both ids are null, the equals will return true. Only if one ID isn't.

Comment: sorry,,,I have updated my code. Both object properties have the same value..but I get failure....

Comment: Only thing I see now ist the missing ")", I hope you have it right in your code?            
if(a1.contains(clsA2) <<==
{
    System.out.println("Success");
}
else
{ 
    System.out.println("Failure");
}

Comment: Sorry folks....it was my fault. I was getting the data from a table that I was not supposed to be using. That was giving results that I did not anticipate and hence  this question. The above code works just fine. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a "Failure" because you're checking if `a1` contains `clsA2` when you haven't added `clsA2` to `a1`.  Checking if `a2.contains(clsA2)` should print "Success"

Comment: well my idea is to compare if there is an object of clsA2 which is equivalent to something in clsA1 that is in the array containing objects of type clsA1.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Seems like that should have worked then.  I would try stepping through the equals method with the debugger to see which check is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy-pasted and tested your code. I got Success. You missed only a parenthesis after `a1.contains(clsA2)`. The eclipse-generated `equals()` does handle `null` properly.